# If I deleted all my git meta files by accident how do I fix it

Tags: git

On a secondary git worktree I was trying to fix something and instead I deleted all the meta info in .git/worktrees/git-2/ e.g. index, head, orig-head, log/.

I still have my changes in the working directory but I have messed up and am very very concerned what do I do

Comment: is the repo stored remotely (githu, gitlab, etc) or is it just local?

Comment: If you only deleted the metadata for the worktree, just create a new work tree (or a new branch in the main directory), and then copy over your changed files from the old worktree.